# In Oracle, am I getting the ORA-01438 error because my values are too small (i.e rather than too large)?

Tags: sql, oracle

One of my columns have the type of  NUMBER(8,2)  (for salaries ).

If I put the value of  '1234'  , will this cause a bug ?

I've been getting the error :

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01438: value larger than specified
>   precision allowed for this column

And I don't see any of my  columns going over the limits. So I'm wondering if I *have* to supply exactly what the  type is : i.e ,   NUMBER(8,2)  means I must have 8 places and 2 decimals.

thnaks

Comment: No, that should be fine.  The error is happening because of some other data.

Comment: @sstan - Ok , understood - thanks ! I will look closer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the oracle PLSQL docs:

> For example, number(8,2) is a number that has 6 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal.

Therefore your example will fit this data type fine.